# Is it justified to take orbital as just a "dispersed region of charge" for applications in Organic chemistry?

Tags: orbitals, quantum-chemistry

When I read organic chemistry book in the past, it seems so a heuristic used to explain and understand reaction mechanism is that negative charge attracts positive charge (or indirectly as nucleophiles going to electrophiles). This I understand is the basis of the [charge transfer arrows](http://www.chem.ucla.edu/%7Eharding/IGOC/C/curved_arrow.html#:%7E:text=Curved%20arrows%3A%20Nonlinear%20arrows%20with,motion%20of%20a%20single%20electron.) in Organic chemistry.

Now, the issue I have when thinking about it again is that, while it is clear that negative and positive attracts in classical electromagnetism, it is unclear how that would play out when considers quantum mechanics. As we typically say that the electrons position is dispersed in the orbital rather than saying it is at a point.

My doubt is how exactly does this electromagnetism intuition of negative and positive charge attracting extend when we talk about orbitals?

Comment: See the links in the answer here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/167332/79678. We all eagerly await Lowe’s “Quantum Mechanics: A Hand-Waving approach”.